# Value of props not diplsaying in child component in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, ecmascript-6

I will share the code of , where props is passed

```
import React ,{useEffect,useState} from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import InfoIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Info';
 import ChatInput from './ChatInput';
import ChatMessage from './ChatMessage'
import db from '../FireBase/FireBase';
import { useParams } from 'react-router';

const Chat = () => {
let {channelId} = useParams();
const [channel, setChannel] = useState()
const[messages , setMessages] = useState([])
const getChannel = ()=>{
    db.collection('rooms')
    .doc(channelId)
    .onSnapshot((snapshot)=>{
        setChannel(snapshot.data())
    })
}

const getMessages = ()=>{
    db.collection('rooms')
    .doc(channelId)
    .collection('Messages')
    .onSnapshot((snapshot)=>{
       let messages = snapshot.docs.map((doc)=>doc.data());
    //    console.log(messages[0].user)  
       setMessages(messages)
    })
}

useEffect(()=>{
       getChannel();
       getMessages();
    },[channelId])

    
return (
    <Container>
        <Header> 
        <Channel>
            <ChannelName>
                #{ channel && channel.name}
            </ChannelName>
            <ChannelInfo>
                A great way to learn react!
            </ChannelInfo>
        </Channel>
        <ChannelDetails>
            <div>
                Details
            </div>
            <Info />
        </ChannelDetails>
        </Header>
        <MessageContainer>
            {
                  messages.length >= 0 &&
                 messages.map((data,index)=>{
                    <ChatMessage  data={data}/>
                  })
                
            }
            
        </MessageContainer>
        <ChatInput />
    </Container>
)
```

}

export default Chat;

Now ,  i will share the code of ChatMessage.js file

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const ChatMessage = ({data}) => {
return (
<Container>
    <UserAvatar>
        <img src={data.userImage} alt="img" />
    </UserAvatar>
    <MessageContent>
        <Name>
            <span>{data.user}</span>
        </Name>
        <Text>
            {data.text}
        </Text>
    </MessageContent>
</Container>
)
 }

 export default ChatMessage
```

Here is an image describing component hierarchy,
[component hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ahe07.png)

since i am using firebase will also add the image of firebase fields,
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnkEq.png)

Don't know why the values are not displayed,can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: getChannel and getMessages maybe return promise? do you handle that logic with async/await or thenable

Comment: console.log() in getChannel and getMessages(). Be sure about response is valid

Comment: I have checked it .It's valid.Thanks for your time @hakiko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code you are missing return statement, you can use ( ) instead of {}

```
{
   messages.length >= 0 &&
   messages.map((data,index)=>(<ChatMessage  data={data}/>
))
}
```